# VueJS -- Select form input when initial value is null

Tags: vuejs2

I have a `locker` object, with a bunch of fields, and a `lots` array of objects -- both passed in via `props`. For the *locker* object, one of the fields holds the `id` of a specific `lot` in the `lots` array. Like so:

```
locker: { locker_num: 'AH3', part_of_lot: '235', allocation: '' , etc...}
```

The `lots` object, is an array of objects, with the structure of:

```
lots: [
  { id: '234', sl_num: '567', etc... },
  { id: '235', sl_num: '567', etc... },
  { id: '236', sl_num: '567', etc... },
  { id: '237', sl_num: '567', etc... },
  ... etc
]
```

I'm trying to present a form to the user to edit the `locker` object. For the `part_of_lot` field, I want to present a `select` input. Here's my code for that:

```
    <select class='form-control' v-model='locker.part_of_lot.id'>
      <option disabled value=''>Choose a Lot</option>
      <option v-for='l in lots' :selected="l.id === locker.part_of_lot.id" :value='l.id'>{{ l.sl_num }}</option>
    </select>
```

This works as expected -- but only when there's already a value in the `part_of_lot` field of `locker`. When I have a `locker` that has the `part_of_lot` field empty, then the above fails. The error is `Cannot read property 'id' of null`.

So how would I setup that `select` input to handle both cases: 1) When `part_of_lot` already has a value and 2) when `part_of_lot` is null?

**EDIT**

If I created a method that simply checks if the `part_of_lot` value is `null` and, if so, changes it to the string `""` then the above code works. But this seems like a clumsy work around. Shouldn't there be a more elegant way to handle this? I feel like there could be many *many* other fields on other models with a value of `null` that need to be dealt with in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've gone with was to have a method that checks the value of `part_of_lot` and changes it to `""` if it is null. Like so:

```
created () {
    this.setToStrings()
  },
  methods: {
    setToStrings () {
      // Simply replaces null values with strings=''
      if (this.locker.part_of_lot === null) {
        this.locker.part_of_lot = ''
      }
      return this.locker
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If the part_of_lot is passed in via props, you can set a default value for it:

```
  props: {
     part_of_lot: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
     }
  }
```

[vuejs props doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation)

you can also add a new field in data:

```
{
 data: function (){
   return {
     new_part_of_lot: this.locker.part_of_lot || "";
   }
 }
}
```

then use new_part_of_lot instead of part_of_lot.

Comment: The `locker` object as a whole is passed in, and in that object is the field `part_of_lot`. But perhaps I could pass in defaults for all fields in the `lot` object. This seems cleanest

Comment: So this didn't work. It maintains the value of `null`

Comment: @Garfonzo maybe you can set a new field in data. updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a computed property `partOfLotID` with `get` and `set` methods referencing the `locker.part_of_lot` object and handling the case of a `null` value:

```
computed: {
  partOfLotID: {
    get() {
      let part = this.locker.part_of_lot;
      return (part) ? part.id : '';
    },
    set(value): {
      let part = this.locker.part_of_lot;
      if (part && typeof part === 'object') {
        this.locker.part_of_lot.id = value;
      } else {
        this.locker.part_of_lot = { id: value };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then just use `partOfLotID` in the `select` instead:

```
<select class='form-control' v-model='partOfLotID'>
  <option disabled value=''>Choose a Lot</option>
  <option 
    v-for='l in lots' 
    :selected="l.id === partOfLotID" 
    :value='l.id'
  >
    {{ l.sl_num }}
  </option>
</select>
```